# How switch to a different user once you're already logged in as another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

*DB Technology: MYSQL*

Hello Everyone,

Someone knows how to switch to different user without exiting?

Many Thanks !!!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394940/how-to-switch-between-users-in-mysql

Comment: Someone want to know what you have tried?

Comment: mysql -u root -h localhost  -p  
Enter password: ****
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 5
Server version: 5.5.8 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>

Comment: Successfully logged in but from here I want to log into another user without exiting mysql and log in again.

Is is possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. However, you can do something a little bit similar.

If you create a view or a stored procedure, you can use `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` to allow the person using the view or stored procedure to run statements within that object as if they are the "definer". You can then use the `DEFINER=user@host` syntax to specify who that definer is.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-security.html for examples of how to do that.