# Access denied for myusername via CLI

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database via the command line. This what I typed:

```
$ mysql
mysql> CREATE DATABASE my_db;

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'my_db'
```

After looking at advice from [ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for 'root' With All Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714869/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-root-with-all-privileges) and [mysql logging in as different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690260/mysql-logging-in-as-different-user), I ran

```
$ mysql -u myusername -p
ENTER PASSWORD: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot log in with created user in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412339/cannot-log-in-with-created-user-in-mysql)

Comment: refer to this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: I can't seem to do all of those suggested. I can't DROP any user or flush privileges because the root user doesn't have any privileges at all?! Then how am I supposed to switch user to myusername???

Comment: maybe the more specific question should be: how do I switch user on MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> maybe the more specific question should be: how do I switch user on MySQL?

Once you have [granted the necessary rights to `myusername`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13076576/6309) (using the mysql `root` account), you can [exit and then re-enter the mysql shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11394982/6309)

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```